# Two solutions to one statement

Tags: align, brackets, delimiters, split

First question here;

Hello, a friend of mine made this a while back, but can't remember the latex code to make it. I need to make it myself and have no idea how this is done. I need to know how. Thank you very much!

PS: he said he used no programs or expansions, only the basic LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
b=\begin{cases}
y_1-ax_1\\
y_2-ax_2
\end{cases}
\]

If amsmath is forbidden:

\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y_1-ax_1\\
y_2-ax_2
\end{array}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Please observe, that the curly brace should be larger than this one in your question.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I add my simple two MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[b=\left\{\begin{matrix} y_1-ax_1& \\ y_2-ax_2& \end{matrix}\right.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{cases}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{numcases}{b=}
      y_1-ax_1 & \nonumber \\ 
      y_2-ax_2 &   \nonumber
    \end{numcases}

    \end{document}
```